# Trouble with passing string to function

Tags: python, pyqt5

I am creating a small GUI using pyqt5 for my python file (that I hope to turn into a .exe file later). 
I've created a very simple GUI where the user selects a date, and the clicks a button that will run the function passing the selected date along with it.
However, I can't seem to get this to work - and i'm sure there is a simple fix but my googling seems to have not worked.

Here's the code I have at the moment:

```
#MainWindow
class GUI(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.setup()

    def setup(self):
        # window settings
        self.setWindowTitle('Create scheule')
        self.resize(505, 556)

        # Date select settings
        calendarWidget = QtWidgets.QCalendarWidget(self)
        calendarWidget.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(50, 160, 392, 236))        
        calendarWidget.clicked[QtCore.QDate].connect(self.showDate)

        self.lbl = QLabel(self)
        date = calendarWidget.selectedDate()
        self.lbl.setText(date.toString("MM/dd/yyyy"))
        self.lbl.move(20, 20)

        # create schedule button settings
        cleaned_date = date.toString("MM/dd/yyyy")
        Create_schedule = QtWidgets.QPushButton('Create schedule',self)
        Create_schedule.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(120, 460, 261, 61))        
        Create_schedule.clicked.connect(self.create_schedule)


    def showDate(self, date):
        self.lbl.setText(date.toString("MM/dd/yyyy"))
        cleaned_date = date.toString("MM/dd/yyyy")
        print(cleaned_date)

    def create_schedule(self, cleaned_date):

        print(cleaned_date)
        creating_schedules(cleaned_date)

        print('created it :D')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)

    gui = GUI()
    gui.show()

    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

The gui opens up and selects date (I used the showDate function to check that it was creating a string in the format I needed). However, when I run the function: creating_schedules(cleaned_date) that I imported from another file, it tries to run the function, but the 'cleaned_date' value it is being passed is a boolean : False. Im expecting it be passed the same string as was created within the setup - and i'm unsure why it is changing the string to False.

I also tried to move the cleaned_date into create_schedule, but this came up with the same error.

Any help is greatly appreciated, thank you!

Comment: How does the `connect()` method know that it should pass the `cleaned_date` variable when it calls `self.create_schedule`?

Comment: I'm not sure, when i try to pass it as self.create_scheule(cleaned_date), it comes up with an error saying "TypeError: argument 1 has unexpected type 'NoneType'"

Comment: @AdamLaird The [clicked signal](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qabstractbutton.html#clicked) always sends the button's checked-state, which will clobber your `cleaned_date` argument.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to basically change two things:

```
   # Date select settings
        calendarWidget = QtWidgets.QCalendarWidget(self)
        calendarWidget.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(50, 160, 392, 236))
        calendarWidget.clicked[QtCore.QDate].connect(self.showDate)
        ########## CHANGE HERE!
        self.calendar_widget = calendarWidget # this line is new
```

and

```
 def create_schedule(self, cleaned_date):
        cleaned_date = self.calendar_widget.selectedDate().toString("MM/dd/yyyy")
        print(cleaned_date)
        #creating_schedules(cleaned_date)

        print('created it :D')
```

The problem is that your button does not know about the calender widget. So it will not pass the value of the calender to the function create_schedule.

Answer (score 0):

At the top of your setup method add this line

```py
self.cleaned_date = ''
```

**or** you can add

```py
self.cleaned_date = date.toString("MM/dd/yyyy")
```

this line after you assigned date.

Then reference it like this:

```py
def create_schedule(self):

    print(cleaned_date)
    creating_schedules(self.cleaned_date)

    print('created it :D')
```

I usually make my variables class variables in PyQt5. I don't know a better way to achieve this, if anybody does, correct me.

Comment: Shouldn't it be `self.cleaned_date = date.toString("MM/dd/yyyy")`?

Comment: I usually just specify the type first in the ```__init__``` (or setup) method, and then fill it with content. If you write that into setup method you reference```date``` before assignment.

Comment: But you're not doing the assignment in the `__init__` method, it's in `setup`, which has the `date` variable.

Comment: Well, after ```date = calendarWidget.selectedDate()``` this line, you can do that.

Answer (score 0):

Try it:

```
import sys
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
from PyQt5.QtCore    import *
from PyQt5.QtGui     import *
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *


class GUI(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.setup()

    def setup(self):
        # window settings
        self.setWindowTitle('Create scheule')
        self.resize(505, 556)

        # Date select settings
        calendarWidget = QtWidgets.QCalendarWidget(self)
        calendarWidget.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(50, 160, 392, 236))        
        calendarWidget.clicked[QtCore.QDate].connect(self.showDate)

        self.lbl = QLabel(self)
        date = calendarWidget.selectedDate()
        self.lbl.setText(date.toString("MM/dd/yyyy"))
        self.lbl.move(20, 20)

        # create schedule button settings
        self.cleaned_date = date.toString("MM/dd/yyyy")                  # + self.
        Create_schedule = QtWidgets.QPushButton('Create schedule',self)
        Create_schedule.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(120, 460, 261, 61))        
        Create_schedule.clicked.connect(self.create_schedule)


    def showDate(self, date):
        self.lbl.setText(date.toString("MM/dd/yyyy"))
        self.cleaned_date = date.toString("MM/dd/yyyy")                  # + self.
        print(self.cleaned_date)                                         # + self.

#    def create_schedule(self, cleaned_date):
    def create_schedule(self):

        print(self.cleaned_date)                                         # + self.
#        creating_schedules(cleaned_date)

        print('created it :D')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)

    gui = GUI()
    gui.show()

    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the help. I have fixed it from a previous answer, but it was the missing of the 'self.' added on.

Comment: @AdamLaird  see `def create_schedule(self):`